# How do I substitute the entire line in a text file for a portion of text in the line?

Tags: linux, perl

For example, I would like to make:

```
>sid|RSV210|ref|NC_001803.1| SM:RSV210
```

turn into

```
>RSV210
```

I believe that I could use sed to do this by the following

```
"s/>.*/>RSV210/"
```

but I would like to do this across multiple text files in one directory (containing a different number after the letters RSV). How would I achieve this across multiple files?

Comment: (1) Your `sed` replaces everything after `>`, even if `>` is in the middle of the line. I understand `>` is our indicator. Right? Should it work even mid-line? (2) Your `sed` does not detect `RSV`. What if there is no `RSV` in a line indicated by `>`? (3) There are two `RSV210` substrings in your input. Which one counts? Any? (4) What about `|ZRSV210|`? What about `|RSV210non-digit|`? (5) Do you think you can easily specify "multiple text files in one directory"? Or do you need help with like creating a glob pattern? // Please respond by [edit]ing the question and clarifying your requirements.

Comment: *Maybe* all these can be compacted to "in lines starting with `>` keep the `>` and replace the rest with the second `|`-separated field". This seems quite elegant. Or maybe "in lines starting with `>` and where the second `|`-separated field is `RSV`digits keep the `>` and…". The problem is we don't know it until you tell us.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only the RSV values you can use for example such construction

```
cat ./* | grep RSV| awk 'BEGIN{RS="|"} {print}' | grep "^RSV"
```

I little bit didn't understand what is the deal with first symbol. Is it important or you just can write it ? Hope it help you.

Comment: You should read the above comments from @Kamil before answering.